# vedio conferance app is getting stuck at certain point

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

this is the breakpoint which I am getting

```
 await sendUserData(
    toChannel: true,
    username: sessionController.value.connectionData!.username!,
    sessionController: sessionController,
  );
```

my code

```
import 'package:agora_uikit/agora_uikit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class VedioCall extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
State<VedioCall> createState() => _VedioCallState();
}
class _VedioCallState extends State<VedioCall> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    initAgora();
  }
  void initAgora()async{
    await _client.initialize();
  }
 final AgoraClient _client = AgoraClient(agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
    appId: "fb22af9381804b26a819c224dd64c13b",
    tempToken: "006fb22af9381804b26a819c224dd64c13bIACyo06QHucaP6FB/bqFygBI94UWAnIwtCFaMQfjjhQabgx+f9gAAAAAEACGukDPOjniYgEAAQA4OeJi",
    channelName: "test"
  ),
  enabledPermission: [
    Permission.microphone,
    Permission.camera
  ]
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
                children: [
                  AgoraVideoViewer(
                    
                    showAVState: true,
        showNumberOfUsers: true,
          client: _client,layoutType:Layout.floating,
        disabledVideoWidget: Container(
          color: Colors.black,child:
           Center(child: Text("User disabled the vedio",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),),),
                    
                  ),
                  AgoraVideoButtons(client: _client)
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

- Plz help me to get rid of this error
- The error which i am getting is
- await sendUserData(toChannel: true,
  username: sessionController.value.connectionData!.username!,
  sessionController: sessionController,
  );

Comment: There is no call to sendUserData in your code. Can you share the full stacktrace and point out what part of your code is ulitimately calling sendUserData?

Comment: sorry sir I dint get@activout.se